# Having more than one schema configured in Prisma in a nodeJS project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, orm, prisma

Is it possible to have more than one schema configuring for the prisma?
I know you can configure a schema in package.json, I would like to know if you can do this with two different bases.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood well, but I think that you are looking for something like [this](https://github.com/jamiepine/prismix)